# OpenLayers 3 draw and modify with snap

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm getting started with **OpenLayers 3** on top of the [Snap Interaction](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/snap.html) example and I want to add a `None` option in the dropdown menu.

I added the option:

```
  <select name="draw-type" id="draw-type">
    <option value="None">None</option>
    <option value="Point">Point</option>
    <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
    <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
    <option value="MultiPolygon">MultiPolygon</option>
  </select>
```

Then a condition like in [Draw Features](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/draw-features.html) example:

```
  var typeSelect = document.getElementById('draw-type');
  var value = typeSelect.value;
  if (value !== 'None') {

  }
```

But it's not clear to me where to insert the condition and if this is the correct way of doing it.

Thank you, sir.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/i5ar/r199j3k8/)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this little hack:

```
<select name="draw-type" id="draw-type">

    <!-- Add None option -->
    <option value="None">None</option>

    <option value="Point">Point</option>
    <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
    <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
    <option value="MultiPolygon">MultiPolygon</option>
</select>
```

Then:

```
init: function() {

    // Add None option
    map.removeInteraction(this.None);
    this.None.setActive(false);

    map.addInteraction(this.Point);
    this.Point.setActive(false);
    map.addInteraction(this.LineString);
    this.LineString.setActive(false);
    map.addInteraction(this.Polygon);
    this.Polygon.setActive(false);
    map.addInteraction(this.MultiPolygon);
    this.MultiPolygon.setActive(false);
},

// Add None option
None: new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vector.getSource(),
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Point')
}),
```

Maybe it is not the cleanest solution but it works!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/i5ar/r199j3k8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Set a change event to the select element and remove the draw interaction from the map if the value is None. If the value is not None, add the draw interaction back to the map after testing that it is not already added.

Comment: I found a solution and answered myself. Now, is there a way to get some data? For instance when a polygon is closed...

Comment: draw.on('drawend',function(e){});